# How do I set Angular 2 ngModel from a firebase observable on a select dropdown

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am trying to set the default value in a select dropdown from a firebase object using angularfire 2. But I don't know how to make it work with setting the default value of the select box. ngModel doesn't allow something like `(ngModel)="(default_tax | async)"`

code:

```
public default_tax$:Observable<any>;
public tax$:Observable<Tax>;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.tax$ = this.db.list(`tax_rates`);
    this.default_tax$ = this.db.object(`settings/default_tax_rate`);
}
```

template:

```
<select name="tax_rate" (ngModel)="default_tax.$key" (ngModelChange)="onSelect($event)">
    <option  *ngFor="let tax of (taxes$ | async)" [ngValue]="tax.$key">
    {{tax.name}} - {{tax.rate}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Firebase object:

```
account:
    setttings:
         default_tax_rate: "-somekey"
    tax_rates:
         "-somekey":
              "name":"5.5"
         "-someotherkey"
               "anothername":"4.5"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found out how to do this. I was writing the ngModel wrong.
WRONG:

```
(ngModel)="default_tax.$key"
(ngModel)="(default_tax | async)"
```

CORRECT:

```
[ngModel]="(default_tax | async)?.$value"
```

> Note that ngModel is wrapped with `[]` instead of `[()]` or `()`. Brackets`[]` indicate input, where parenthesis`()` indicate output. Having both `[()]` is for two-way binding (both input and output).

A great guide to help understand this in more details is http://blog.ng-book.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-forms-in-angular-2/